# Sharing collections between client and server and private server methods

Tags: meteor

I have methods that should never be seen/called from the client. The only way these private 'helper' methods should be invoked, is through Meteor method declarations on the server.

I have tried to do this, but for some reason I am not able to share my collection definitions, even though they're placed in a lib folder

lib/collections/tabs.js

```
Tabs = new Mongo.Collection('tabs');
```

server/lib/collections/tabs.js

```
_.extend(Tabs, {
  /* Increments download count
   */
  incrementDownloadsCount: function(tabId) {
    Tabs.update({_id: tabId}, { $inc: { downloads: 1 } }, function(error, result) {
      if (error) { throw new Meteor.Error(error.mesage); }
    });
  }
```

});

Any idea as to why this is, and if this is the correct approach for private server methods?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear for me, what your question is.

- If you want to hide collections from the client, you should use Meteor.methods() like described in http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-methods. This will result in calling logic on the server, without allowing the client directly manipulate collections
- If you want to share collections with server and client, your approach is correct, to place the collection definition in a file e.g. in the lib folder.
- If you want to share collections with server and client and do NOT want that the client can manipulate the collection, you have to remove the meteor insecure package and use Collection.allow or Collection.deny respectively to control what is allowed in what cirumstances see here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-allow

Hope that helps to get the direction.

Comment: I dont want the client to be able to call/view the helper methods. And because I define the helper methods by extending the collection, I need to have access to this on both the server and client. But the problem is that even though I defined the collection in the lib folder, I get an undefined error when refering to this on the server

Comment: @Tarlen What do you want to achieve by extending the collection instead of using the recommended `Meteor.methods()` approach?

Comment: `Meteor.methods` can be called from the client, I dont want this. By declaring these methods on the server, outside of meteor methods, they essentially becomes private. Also, I only extend the collection as a way to structure/namespace the code.